# Let, $|G| = 105$, prove that $G$ is cyclic if $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, sylow-theory

We have that, $|G| = 105 = 3*5*7$. We have that, $n_{7} \in \{1,14\}$ and $n_{5} \in \{1,21\}$ by Sylow Theorem. Suppose, $n_{7} = 14$ and $n_{5}= 21$. Then,
$$14*7 - 14 + 5*21 -21 + 1 > 105,$$
because the Sylow subgroup of order $5$ and order $7$ do not intersect with each other, and the Sylow subgroups of order $5$ ($7$) do not intersect amongst themselves. Thus, $n_{7} = 1$ or $n_{5} = 1$. WLOG, let $n_{5} = 1$. We will let $A$ be normal subgroup of order $3$, $B$ be a subgroup of order $5$, and $C$ be the normal subgroup of order $7$. We have that,
$|AB| = 3*5$, and then $|ABC| = 3*5*7$; thus, $G\simeq \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{7}$. Since each constituent of the direct product is cyclic and their orders are co-prime, we can conclude that $G$ is cyclic as well.

Does my proof look good? Any issues? Thanks!

Comment: I think  $n_7$ can not be 14 but 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to establish that the Sylow $7$ subgroup is normal.   That can be done by counting again. That will finish your solution.

Note that $n_7\in\{1,15\}$ by Sylow.